# Why is the program not running the main function of a flex and bison compiled C program

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I've written a *bison parser* using *flex and c*. The parser is compiled without error, but when I run the executable file the main function is not executed (It doesn't print out the first line after the main declaration that is actually a print instruction)

```
main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  printf("*** C2P version 1.0 @2015***\n");
  extern FILE *yyin;
  ++argv; --argc;
  printf("Open C file %s...",argv[0]);
  yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
  if (yyin==NULL) {
  printf("ERROR file not found %s", argv[0]);
  exit(1);
}
  yydebug = 1; //enable debug
  yyparse();
  exit(0);
}
```

I've used the following commands for compiling:

```
bison -d c_def.y
flex c_def.l
gcc c_def.tab.h lex.yy.c -o c2p -lfl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
gcc c_def.tab.h lex.yy.c -o c2p -lfl
```

The bison parser is in the file `c_def.tab.c`. `c_def.tab.h` is just the header file containing the token definitions.

So there wouldn't be a `main()` at all in `c2p` if it were not for your inclusion of the flex library (`-lfl`). That library includes a `main` function which calls the lexer until it returns an end-of-file indicator. (It does not call the parser, which is why your parser is not being called.)

You probably shouldn't use `-lfl`. Aside from the `main()` function which you don't need, the only other thing it contains is a fake implementation of `yywrap` which always returns 1; instead of relying on that, just include the option

```
%option noyywrap
```

in your flex definition, and then your lexer won't depend on `yywrap` at all.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. Moreover, your comments about -lfl are very useful.